# How to Change User Input Date Format in Razor Pages without Affecting Backend Date Format?

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, abp

I’m working on an ASP.NET Core project using the ABP Framework and Razor pages. Currently, the user inputs a date in the format `yyyy/MM/dd`, which is then saved to the database in the same format.

The relevant code in my Razor page is as follows:

```
<abp-column size-md="_4" size-sm="_12">
    <abp-input asp-for="@Model.Employee.OnboardDate" label=@L["ContractStart"]></abp-input>
</abp-column>
```

And this is my `EmployeeDto`:

```
public DateTime? OnboardDate { get; set; }
```

I would like to change the user input format to `dd/MM/yyyy` for a better user experience, but keep the `yyyy/MM/dd` format when saving to the database to avoid breaking anything else.

I tried the following:

```
<abp-column size-md="_4" size-sm="_12">
    <abp-input asp-for="@Model.Employee.OnboardDate" value="@Model.Employee.OnboardDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace(" ", "")" label=@L["ContractStart"]></abp-input>
</abp-column>
```

However, I get an error in the inspect element console:

> the specified value "04/01/2024" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

How can I allow the user to enter the date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, but still save the date in `yyyy/MM/dd` format to the database?

Comment: What database system are you using? Most relational databases will store date&time not in a formatted string style - but in a binary format, entirely independent of any formatting. Which format you're using when *displaying* the date&time is totally up to you

Comment: Like @marc_s said, your comment about storing datetimes in a particular format rings a loud warning bell.  I wrote an article about working with Dates and Times in Razor Pages forms: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times. It includes info on the format required for the `datetime-local` input.

Comment: Where is that error actually coming from? That looks like a custom error, possibly from the ABP framework?

Comment: @marc_s 

Hi Marc, We are using EF Core with a SQL Server Database. The default format for inputting seems to be yyyy/mm/dd. I just want that to be flipped.

Comment: @MikeBrind

Thanks Mike! I will check out that article

Comment: @StevePy 
Hi Steve, The error message is coming from the browser’s console. When I try to open the CreateOrUpdateModal where the input is. All I want is for the user to be able to input a date in the dd/mm/yyyy format instead of the default yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: I would suggest to use the ABP date picker tag helper not the abp-input.  The default format of the date always depends on the select culture. You could check it here ->  https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Tag-Helpers/Form-elements